# Why UIFont support mutableCopy selector?

Tags: objective-c

Do we have UIMutableFont or what?

What to do if I want the same font but with say a slightly bigger size?

Update: I tested and it causes run time error. The question is then changed. Why it's run time error rather than compile error.

```
[self.Title.font mutableCopy]
```

will actually compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`mutableCopy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/mutableCopy)
documentation (emphasis mine):

> This is a convenience method for classes that adopt the
>   `NSMutableCopying` protocol. **An exception is raised** if there is no
>   implementation for `mutableCopyWithZone:`.

And from the [NSMutableCopying Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) reference:

> `NSMutableCopying` declares one method, `mutableCopyWithZone:`, but mutable copying is
>   commonly invoked with the convenience method mutableCopy.
>   The `mutableCopy` method is defined for **all `NSObjects`** and simply invokes
>   mutableCopyWithZone: with the default zone.

So

```
 [someObject mutableCopy];
```

will *always* compile, but fail at runtime if the object does not implement
`mutableCopyWithZone:`.

The same is true for `copy` vs `copyWithZone:`.

Answer (score 1):

UIFont is immutable and we do not have option of UIMutableFont. It does not support mutableCopy selector because it does not conforms to NSMutableCopying.

But, if you want to change size of a font object, you can use *fontWithSize:* API.
for example:

```
//creating font
```

`UIFont *someFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"font-name" size:15.0f];`

`UIFont *biggerFont = [someFont fontWithSize:17.0f];`

Unfortunately, you have to keep separate Font objects for different sizes.
I think the best way is to keep Font macro something like:

```
#define HEL_NEUE(xx)                    [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:xx]
```

You can use it wherever you want and just pass the required size accordingly.

Comment: No no no no no. No macros that are actually masked methods. If necessary, just do a category on `UIFont` with methods like `+[UIFont helveticaNeueFontWithSize:]`.